# Detect the completion of Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, core-animation

So,

I perform a simple animation with `CABasicAnimation` (as shown below).

```
CAAnimationGroup *theGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
theGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
theGroup.removedOnCompletion = NO;
theGroup.delegate = self;
theGroup.timingFunction =[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

theGroup.duration = inDuration;
theGroup.repeatCount = 0;
theGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rotationZ, theAnimationX, theAnimationY, nil]; // you can add more

[inLayer addAnimation:theGroup forKey:@"animateLayer"];

NSLog (@"ABCD");
// This gets called before end of animation
```

Is there any method like `-(BOOL) isAnimationCompleted;` so that I could know when animation is completed ?

I want to run a method right after animation has come to a complete end . Any ideas ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implement the method

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
```

which you can see the doc from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CAAnimation).

Comment: This method does not return anything.

Comment: Yeah, its return type is `void`. But you will be informed that animation has been completed through this delegate method. Then , you can call the required method inside this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a category to create a method like this:

```
[group setCompletionBlock:^{

}];
```

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28051909/1485701